# How to add a new property to an existing vertex in gremlin?

Tags: graph, gremlin, rexster

I have trouble finding a way of adding a new property to an existing vertex using gremlin.
ex property to add: the property "name" with value "anna".

First I try to find the vertex which I want to add the property to. I do this by:
g.v(id), where id is the id of the vertex I'm looking for.

Then I've tried adding the property to the vertex by doing:
g.v(id).property("name","anna"), but this does not work and gives me an error saying:

```
"message":"","error":"javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No
signature of method: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException.property() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values:
```

It says here http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/3.0.0.M1/#giraph-gremlin under "Mutation the graph" that this is the way to add a new property to an existing vertex.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are reading the TP3 docs, but it looks like you're using TP2. In TP2 it's ```g.v(id).setProperty("name","anna")```.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with `sideEffect`:

```
g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
g.V[0].map
==>{name=lop, lang=java}
g.V[0].sideEffect{it.foo = 'bar'}
g.V[0].map
==>{name=lop, foo=bar, lang=java}
```

I guess in a script you would need to add an `.iterate()` at the end of the modification statement.